# selection using getElementbyname

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, radio-button, getelementsbytagname

so we are suppose to write script for multiple radio buttons, different types of tacos with different prices, then we are to calculate the total with tax and display it. this is my javascript thus far, I feel i'm just missing a couple of steps

```
function btnCalculate_onclick()
    {  
        var taco = document.getElementsByName("radTaco");
        var total = document.getElementById("txtTotal");
        var deliv = document.getElementById("chkDelivery");
        var tax = 1.13 
        var totalPrice = 0;
        var delivCost = parseFloat(deliv.value);

        for( var i = 0; i < taco.length; i++)
        {           
            if(taco[i].checked)
            {
                if(deliv.checked)
                    totalPrice + delivCost;

                totalPrice = parseFloat(taco[i].value);
                tax = totalPrice * 1.13;
                totalPrice + tax;  
                break;
            }   
        }

    total.value = totalPrice.value;  
    }
```

Comment: This is very suspicious looking Java. What version is this?

Comment: are you getting the correct value? Could you please explain a bit more? what is the expected outcome?

Comment: expected outcome is the price of the tacos in a display box including tax, the user also has the choice of adding a delivery fee

Comment: `totalPrice + delivCost;` and `totalPrice + tax;` does nothing - effectively you add the two, then discard the result = you need to assign the result to something.

Comment: For the sake of creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd get rid of the document.getElementsByName and just hard code values so that people can more easily reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`totalPrice + delivCost;` and `totalPrice + tax;` does nothing - effectively you add the two, then discard the result = you need to assign the result to something.

I'd also add the delivery cost after getting the value

```
function btnCalculate_onclick() {

    var taco = document.getElementsByName("radTaco");
    var total = document.getElementById("txtTotal");
    var deliv = document.getElementById("chkDelivery");
    var tax = 1.13 
    var totalPrice; // no need to initialise
    var delivCost = parseFloat(deliv.value);

    for( var i = 0; i < taco.length; i++)
    {

        if(taco[i].checked)
        {
            totalPrice = parseFloat(taco[i].value);

            if(deliv.checked)
                totalPrice += delivCost;


            tax = totalPrice * 1.13;

            totalPrice += tax;

            break;
        }

    }

    total.value = totalPrice.value
```